# When is it viable to build a gold per 10 item on a carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

Usually supports are the ones getting the GP/10 items, but I've seen a few carries building those items.

When is it viable to build a GP/10 on a carry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only time you would want to build a gold/10 item on a carry is if it is building into an item you are already getting (i.e. ghostblade, deathfire grasp).  A gold/10 item takes about 13 minutes to pay for its purchase (if you are selling it) in a game.  This is 12 minutes that your income is locked into an item when you could be building something else.  Supports get them because they will ideally be leaving all the creeps to the carries and need income.  Only build on a carry if it is beneficial to your end build, not as gold boost for a short time.

Comment: I like the points that @Kirkalirk made, but when it comes to a carry getting this item I do believe a good portion of the time it should only be done when it is being made into another item.

Comment: My problem with @kirkalirk points is that you can get other items you would want to keep.  A gold/10 item (like heart of gold for health) that I am only going to sell only pays itself off after 12.5 minutes, I would prefer to get something that will benefit my build that I would not want to just sell off later.  I can see where the gold income would be useful in solo top case though

Answer (score 3):

Assume a [minion](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Minions) is worth 20 gold.  At most points in the game, they will be worth more than this.

So a single GP/10 item ([philosopher's stone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher's_Stone), [heart of gold](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_Gold), etc) gives 5 gold every 10 seconds, or 30 gold/minute.  In minion terms, this is 1.5 minions every minute.

Any item is better than a GP/10 item if it helps you get more than 1.5 minion kills per minute.  As the game progresses, less minion kills are needed to equal GP/10 items.

**GP/10 items are rarely the best item for a carry.**  The only reason to consider one would be it's other benefits, like the health/mana regen on a philosopher's stone.  Even then, masteries offer comparable benefits.

The only time to consider a GP/10 item on a carry is if you're getting less than 2 minion kills a minute.

Comment: And if you're getting less than 2 minion kills a minute, then you probably shouldn't be playing carry :P.

Comment: With the end of Season 3, the math in this comment is no longer accurate.  Some of the new GP items are now quite viable on carries.

Answer (score 1):

i wouldnt suggest it on mid or bot lane, as you get to farm by yourself for the majority of the lane phase. its a waste of gold that you could be using on items to get ahead of your opponent. but on a top lane such as gangplank or irelia or malphite, if you can farm early and get a kill or two, getting an early gp10 is useful to be more tanky/have more sustainablity and to be ahead in gold.

Comment: The answer is kinda moot since, he is asking specifically when it is beneficial to build on a carry. Your answer focused more on why to build it on the top lane offtanks rather than what the OP is really asking.

Comment: To be fair I think he actually did address the question.  He gave reason for not building it, and example of when it might actually have been beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with some of the previous replies.  I believe there is a point where a GP10 item is good on a carry.  Most of the statements have said that if it builds into something then you should get it.  By this statement, champs should not buy Doran's items because they don't build into anything and only grant minimal help but so many people purchase them.  I believe however, if you are a carry and you are getting zoned (unable to farm because of an unfavorable match up) heavily or if the enemy you are facing has ganked well or is ahead in kills and in level by a few levels it is valuable to pick this up.  That way you can still keep pace with the opposing team without losing the value you personally give up by being killed. Just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you can win the lane regardless, and/or it is just a farmfest, getting gp10 items will give you the advantage.  However, the fact that gp10 items are not efficient stats in terms of the money you put into them usually means that your opponent will have the upperhand over you if they buy towards core items or dorans while you just have gp10 items.